# Insert an Array into Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have tried many methods to insert my array into my PHPmyAdmin Database through localhost. None have worked so far. I believe I may be mixing too many different solutions together. I may be trying to insert the INT incorrectly.

Im basing my solution on this reference: https://www.phpflow.com/php/insert-php-array-into-mysql-table/

```
$result = array( "0" => array(1, "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", 2, 3),
                 "1" => array(2, "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", 4, 5));

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if(is_array($result)){
foreach ($result as $row) {  
    $fieldVal0 = (int) $result[$row][0];
    $fieldVal1 = mysql_real_escape_string($result[$row][1]);
    $fieldVal2 = mysql_real_escape_string($result[$row][2]);
    $fieldVal3 = mysql_real_escape_string($result[$row][3]);
    $fieldVal4 = mysql_real_escape_string($result[$row][4]);
    $fieldVal5 = (int) $result[$row][5];
    $fieldVal6 = (int) $result[$row][6];

    $query ="INSERT INTO testtable ( id, english, navajoVerb, person, mode, verbNum, bookNum) VALUES ( '". $fieldVal0."','".$fieldVal1."','".$fieldVal2."','". $fieldVal3."','".$fieldVal4."','".$fieldVal5."','".$fieldVal6."' )";

    mysqli_query($connect,$query);  
}
}
```

[image of my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8omb.png)

Comment: For starters you're using the wrong function. mysqli_query, you're missing the "i".

Comment: second `$row` is not the index here, it's the actual row/array. So: `$fieldVal0 = (int) $row[0];` (and so on..)

Comment: third: use prepared statements! It's saver and you could get rid of all the `$fieldVal`s - saves you at least 4 error prone lines.

Comment: forth: check the [mysqli::error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see what's going wrong

Comment: where would I put the error code in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe mysqli is depricated since php 5.5.x,
Anyhow i recommend using [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) when working with databases and PHP.
it makes escaping your data also a lot easier.

1: Where does $records come from within the if statement?
cause if it isn't it never gets past that.

2: You declare the numeric values as strings within your nested array's
not sure if typecasting is the best solution. You could use just integers.

```
array(1, "blah" ....
```

This might work:

```
 $result = array( "0" => array(1, "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", 2, 3),
                 "1" => array(2, "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", 4, 5));

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if(is_array($result))
{


    // First array ( 0 and 1) 
    foreach ($result as $key =>$row) 
    {
        // We can just loop over the next array so we have to type less
        // lets declare a new array with escaped results

        $escaped_results = array();

        // Now loop over the row
        foreach( $row as $key => $value)
        {
            // if we don't set anything inbetween the brackets [] we tell php to auto fill the array 
            // so it adds a new array element starting from 0 
            $escaped_results[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $value);
        }

        // lets make the query easier and simpler
        // we just use implode to build the values 
        $query ="INSERT INTO testtable ( id, english, navajoVerb, person, mode, verbNum, bookNum) VALUES ('". implode("','", $escaped_results) ."')";

        // execute the query
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  

        // catch the error
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
        }
    }
}
```

Although i would recommend getting some PDO tutorials for php
as that will make life a lot easier for you.

Comment: thanks, sorry, I copied some wrong items into the question. I have corrected them in the question, and adhered to your answer, but still nothing is inserting into the database.

Comment: Alright, you've got any errors when running the script? 
and you're also sure you're running a sql server?

Comment: yes, im sure im connected, because I do other things with another database on the localhost, and Im communicating fine with it..

Comment: i altered the code so you might want to retry it. meanwhile i see if i can help you a bit :)

Comment: Okay i've been looking at it and it seems PHP 7.0.0 and beyond completely removed the function mysql_real_escape_string
Lets just say its not worth learning mysqli, so please start looking into PDO. that said i will still help you solve this.

Comment: hey! everything finally worked for me! thank you so much for putting the time in. I have one last question.. if the text that I want to insert into the database are unicode characters, how can I specify that?

Comment: I believe you've got to use utf-8 characterset for that.
mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8")
should work

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach `$row` is your array, not the key ("0", "1") you just need to change your code to use $row[0] like this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {  
    $fieldVal0 = (int) $row[0];
    $fieldVal1 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]);
    $fieldVal2 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[2]);
    $fieldVal3 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[3]);
    $fieldVal4 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[4]);
    $fieldVal5 = (int) $row[5];
    $fieldVal6 = (int) $row[6];
}
```

Comment: still nothing inserting into the database =/

Comment: Does it print some error? If you print the query it is ok?

Comment: no errors. I put print $query right after the line that I declare it, but nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have `display_errors` enabled? you can do it by putting this code at the start of your php `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`